# Tool for listing subsites and size

Tags: 2007

Does anyone know of a tool that lists all site collections and subsites together with quote size/usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used a free tool from CodePlex for this, and its worked out really well: http://www.codeplex.com/SPUsedSpaceInfo

You'll have to run it a separate time for each site collection you want to get numbers for, but the only really problem I had with it. I like the way it outputs the results to a comma-separated value (CSV) file for you, makes it alot easier to get that data into a readable, manageable, and reportable format.

If you need sizing for each site collection, try STSADM's EnumSites operation, I believe it displays the storage used by each site collection, and you can easily pipe its output to a text file as well.

John

Comment: Thanks John. Very useful and did the trick. I found I had to rename the CSV files to .txt in order to get Excel 2007 to format it properly but otherwise a great little tool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are some third party tools out there that you can pay for that does this.  At work we wrote our own tool that dumps all of the site information into a db where we can quickly look up that info using sql statements or if we needed to expose it elsewhere, we could build an app around it.  The code is not that difficult to get the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Manager 2007 off of codeplex.com will do most of this but it is a lazy-load tool in that you have to click on the specifics to obtain the data and doesn't export easily.

You could use also use Powershell to wrap around stsadm.exe that John mentioned above to enumerate your Site Collections, then for each one of those enumsites to gather all their information (you will need a bit of XPath getting the information formatted), and then easily export the data to .csv's or insert into a database.  If interested in some of the scripts, just let me know.